# Many to Many association with Single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

I am looking for a many-to-many association within the child models. Something like this below.  Can you please guide what's the best way to do it.

**`Parent`**

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**`Child1`**

```
class B < A
  has_many :bc
  has_many :c ,through: :bc
end
```

**`Child2`**

```
  class C < A
    has_many :bc
    has_many :b, through: :bc
  end
```

Comment: using one single model with parents and children won't work for you? I mean, do you have to use 3 models?

Comment: yes i have to use 3 models, limitation

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need extra columns, then you just use has_and_belongs_to_many you can read it from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html